# Comments from adb.exe

Tags: android, winapi

How to obtain all comments from adb.exe when it is launched via CreateProcess function (not via cmd):

```
CreateProcess(nil,'adb.exe',nil,nil,false,NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,nil,'',StartupInfo,ProcessInformation);
```

Comment: The documentation for the Win32 CreateProcess API explains how to control the standard streams, and then you'll need some pipes, and threads to read them.

Comment: This is not an answer!!! I read the documentation!!!

Comment: Of course it isn't an answer. It's a comment.

Comment: Such comments are worth nothing and should be removed by the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN has an article that explains and shows how to redirect the input/output of a process created with `CreateProcess()`:

[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx)

Comment: Note: no-one please complain that this is link-only: it points to an MSDN ref that isn't going to be deleted, and does not license to allow it to be pasted here. Maybe the question is too broad, but this answer is as good as it gets.